# Delete query not working in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am simply trying to delete a record from lumen.

My html view button:

```
<li><a href="{!!url('delete-list'. $value->page_id) !!}"class="dangrclr"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</a></li>
```

My controller:

```
public function deleteList($page_id)
{
   $list= DB::table('page_master')->where('page_id',$page_id);
   $list->delete();
    return Redirect::to('page-list');
}
```

and my routes.php file looks like:

```
$router->get('delete-list/{id}', 'AjaxController@deleteList');
```

When i click delete button it shows me

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException
```

and the url it show when i click delete button is:

```
http://localhost:8000/delete-list3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to use `/` in your code. It should be `url('delete-list/'. $value->page_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
<a href="{!!url('delete-list'. $value->page_id) !!}"
```

this

```
<a href="{{ url('delete-list/'.$value->page_id) }}"
```

URL now -  `http://localhost:8000/delete-list3` should be `http://localhost:8000/delete-list/3`

---

As well you can use [**`route()`**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing) as well

```
"{{route('delete-list',$value->page_id)}}"
```